# Importing Swagger API to AWS API Gateway using command line tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-cli, aws-api-gateway

Amazon published this news: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/04/amazon-api-gateway-supports-swagger-definition-import/, saying that now it is possible to import Swagger API using `aws` command line tool.
I am using:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.10.20 Python/2.7.9 Linux/3.16.0-4-amd64 botocore/1.4.11
```

But I can't find a command in `aws apigateway help` that would allow me to import or update API using swagger file.

Currently, we're using [aws-apigateway-importer](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer) for this. Would really great to swtich to `aws` only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is [import-rest-api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/import-rest-api.html).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, as mentioned previously, the command is [import-rest-api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/import-rest-api.html).

```
aws apigateway import-rest-api
```

If your CLI doesn't include this operation, please update to the latest version of the AWS CLI.

Hope this helps.

Best,

Jurgen, API Gateway

Comment: Could you please add an example of using the cli to import a swagger doc?  For the docs, it looks like you must specify the json as a command line parameter.  If there a way to make it load from a file like aws-apigateway-importer?

Comment: Yes, you can also load it from a file. Try 'aws apigateway import-rest-api --body file://./swagger.json'. Another way to do it would be 'aws apigateway import-rest-api --body "$(cat swagger.json)"' on a bash command line. The documentation does not align 100% with the general docs from the AWS CLI though (see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=714211&#714211 for more details). But we are working on fixing that. Hope this helps